# Can I ask a question about DMing published DND adventures for the first time?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79885/how-much-optimization-do-published-dd-adventures-expect/79908#79908) I asked a pretty specific question which I think can/will/is generating useful answers. However some of the comments (before they were removed) suggested that, incidentally, Curse of Strahd was a poor choice.

I know game-recs are offtopic, so I can't ask "What's a good starting adventure for first-time players and DMs?" And "What do I need to know DMing DND for the first time?" seems pretty broad. Would "What do I need to know about running official DND5e adventures for the first time?" fly? Or do I really need a forum for what I'm after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check out our existing questions about [new GMs working with 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnew-gm%5D+AND+%5Bdnd-5e%5D+is%3Aquestion) and [techniques for new GMs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm+gm-techniques). That may help, both with answering the questions you didn't know to ask but someone else already did, and with getting you thinking of specific questions *to* ask.

Generally the Stack works best when we're answering specific problems. "I have the new GM jitters" is hard for us to answer. ["Can my group still level up if I want to run a game without much combat?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53527/4398) is easy.

So, what is it specifically about "official" 5e adventures that you're worried about? Ask that, with the research you've done already, and we can help. It may wind up being multiple questions! If you're having trouble narrowing down what you're concerned about beyond a vague worry that you're missing something, that's a sign to do more research on your own, or ask for help in chat to pin down what to ask about.

Comment: Something along the lines of "What's the problem with Curse of Strahd? I keep hearing negative comments about it and being given warnings to avoid it (and continue...)" seems like it could be a decently answerable question here that might get to the point of the asker's concern.

Comment: Or even "How should I choose an official 5e adventure that will be good for my group?" That could garner some excellent experience-based subjective answers.

Comment: Ding ding ding! @BESW, your last comment is exactly what I needed: [question asked](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79964/how-should-i-choose-a-5e-adventure-for-a-group-of-new-players). If you want to edit it into the answer text for posterity, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SirTechSpec Weirdly, meta has almost the exact opposite attitude toward comments as main site: they're for discussion and only get deleted in the most extreme of circumstances so future people can see the process as well as the final result.